# Transactional Emails: Delivery Address - Company Name missing

Tags: transactional-mail

Whenever we send delivery confirmation emails to customers who have specified a company name in their shipping address, **the company name won't show up in the email.**

Quite a few customers then get back to us to make sure that the delivery address has been recorded properly.
Our shipping module receives all the correct info including the company name, now I would like to find out why this wouldn't work in our **Transactional mails**

The email template contains the following line:

`{{var order.getShippingAddress().format(''html'')}}`

Any hints?
Also, **the configuration inside the backend** didn't show anything unusual on the html template:

> {{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend
>    middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend
>    suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
>
> {{depend dhlaccount}}{{var dhlaccount}} {{/depend}}
>
> {{depend company}}{{var company}} {{/depend}}
>
> {{if street1}}{{var street1}} {{/if}}
>
> {{depend street2}}{{var street2}} {{/depend}}
>
> {{depend street3}}{{var street3}}{{/depend}}
>
> {{depend street4}}{{var street4}}{{/depend}}
>
> {{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}},
>   {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}
>
> {{var country}}
>
> {{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}} {{depend
>   fax}}
> F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}`

If I read this correctly, the company name should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change this in the configuration. A good explanation for Address Display Settings you can find here http://merch.docs.magento.com/ee_docs/content/customers/customer-address-template.html